# SQL Server 2005 CTE hierachical table, managing duplicates, without maxrecursion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The problem I am attempting to solve is a request to pull data from a table using a CTE to retrieve hierarchical data. Because of the nature of the data referencing itself, hitting max recursion is a huge problem but I don't want to arbitrarily stop the data because then it wouldn't be complete. To understand the data, here is what the sample output should look like:

Top Level

```
11552
     - 11414
     - 68775
            - 23667
                   - 65887*
            - 58669*
     - 58669
            - 65887*

11414
     - 58667
            - 11552*
     - 45998
            - 23667
                   - 65887*
            - 33789
     - 26998
            - 11552*
65887
     - 26988
            - 23667
                   - 65887*
            - 45998*
     - 58667
            - 11552*
```

The problem lies in not repeating the chain for items that have already appeared in the hierarchy but still including at least that first value (items marked by asterisk).

UPDATED per request:
The data in the table is structured like this:

```
Id   ProcId   AsscId
1    11552    11414
2    11552    68775
3    11552    58669
4    68775    23667
5    68775    58669
6    23667    65887
7    58669    65887
8    11414    58667
9    11414    45998
10   11414    26998
11   58667    11552
12   45998    23667
13   45998    33789
14   26998    11552
15   65887    26998
16   65887    58667
17   26988    23667
18   26988    45998
```

My initial CTE query (which includes a stop for now) is below. The query only pulls the initial data but I can't figure out how to alter it to meet the request.

```
WITH myCTE AS 
(   
        SELECT ProcId, AsscId, 0 as [Level]
        FROM Associations 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.ProcId, a.AsscId, ([Level] + 1) as RecursionLevel
        FROM Associations a
        INNER JOIN myCTE m ON a.ProcId = m.ProcId
        WHERE ([Level] + 1) <= 2
)
SELECT *  
FROM myCTE 
ORDER BY ProcId
```

I looked at these samples here [How to use Common Table Expression and check no duplication in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750709/how-to-use-common-table-expression-and-check-no-duplication-in-sql-server) and here [Removing duplicates from a CTE based on a specific criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555408/removing-duplicates-from-a-cte-based-on-a-specific-criteria) but I am not certain either helps in this scenario.

POTENTIAL SOLUTION:

So after further searching and some discussion, I learned that in this scenario a CTE really isn't the best choice. Instead, I'm creating a temp table, filling it with the first row of parent data, then calling a separate query that goes to get the additional data. If that query finds there is more data it calls itself again and gets the next level of data. When it goes to get the next level of data it only goes to retrieve that data that does not already exist in the temp table. The temp table holds the value of the ProcId, the parent id, the level on which it was retrieved and a column that holds a boolean value if the id already exists in the temp table. The boolean value will be used indicate if the full data will display or not.

Comment: Are you saying that your graph/tree structure has loops? And you want to prevent infinite recursion caused by these loops? It would really help if you included in your question the data from your table that produces the shown tree.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes, I need to prevent infinite recursion. I updated the question to include the sample data table.

Comment: @ElaineK So, the numbers with asterisk still need to be shown and only up until there, or should they be removed?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu the number itself needs to show but none of its associated data should display beneath it if its already displayed at a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your sample data looks like:

[image: graph]

It has several interconnected loops. I don't know how this can be presented in the form of a tree without some extra information.

You need extra information to tell what node(s) in the loop should become the root node(s) in a tree. In other words, some rule that specifies how the loop should be broken; which links in the graph should be broken.

For the loop `11552 -> 11414 -> 58667` you can choose any node to become the root. But, there are several other loops that go through same nodes, e.g. `11552 -> 11414 -> 45998 -> 23667 -> 65887 -> 58667`; `11552 -> 58669 -> 65887 -> 58667` and more ...

Depending on which link you decide to break the shape of the tree would change.

Having data as is, I would **not** try to present it as a tree, because it is impossible without loosing information about some links. I used [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate the picture shown above and I would try to use this or similar library for this task.

Comment: I was looking back into the temp table to determine if the value already exists at a higher level (has been defined) and if it has, then I break out of that piece and continue with whatever remains. One additional not, decided to move it to a CLR so not actually using temp table any more.